# Transfer Joomla Site from one machine to another

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I made one simple project, at training center and I want to continue that in my home.

I tried by transferring files from WAMP www director to pendrive and storing in my home pc Wamp WWW directory but Getting 404 ARTICLE NOT FOUND ERROR.

I already attached database related with my Joomla project but could not get into Front end.

Answer (score 1):

Two basic options:

I. Have a look at a took like [akeebabackup.com](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html).

II. Do it manually

1. You need to sync the files.
2. You need to dump the database and import it to the other installation.
3. You need to update the configuration.php file to match the settings for database and log / temp folder.

Comment: Upvoted because Akeeba Backup is the best component for moving sites and creating backups.  Takes care of everything from start to finish.